Prove or disprove $F: \mathbb{R} ^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a close map satisfying $|| F(x ,y) || \ge M || (x,y)||$
With regards to this question
Properties of function $F(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$ such that $ \sqrt{u^2+v^2}\geq M\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
I am stuck with the option (c) which is unanswered while I the other options I have done in the same way. The only answer is unclear to me .
So , basically my question is the following.
Let $M$ be a positive real number and $u,v:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be continuous functions satisfying $$\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\geq M\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$$ Let $$F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$$ be given by $$F(x,y)=(u(x,y),v(x,y))$$
Does F necessarily maps closed set to closed set?
I am pretty sure it's not true but can't come up with a example . May be I have to look at a linear transformation and come up with a closed subset whose image is not closed .
Hints Please .

Seems it is true. Let $A$ be a closed set and $F(A)$ be its image. We will prove the image is sequentially closed: for a limit point $a$ for which there exists a sequence of points $\{a_t \in F(A)\}_{t = 0}^{\infty}$ so that $a_t \to a$, it is necessary $a \in F(A)$.
Without loss of generality assume that $|a_t| < |a| + 1$. We can do so as $a_t \to a$ means that $\lim_{t\to \infty}|a - a_t| \to 0$, therefore starting from $t > t_0$ we have $|a - a_t| < 1$, then by the triangle inequality $|a_t|\leq |a_t - a| + |a| < 1 + |a|$ starting from $t > t_0$.
For each $a_t$ choose a preimage: $F(b_t) = a_t$. From the condition on $F$ we know that $\sqrt{b_{t,x}^2 + b_{t,y}^2} \leq M \cdot \sqrt{a_{t,x}^2 + a_{t, y}^2}\leq M\cdot (|a| + 1)$, therefore all $b_t$ lie in a closed disk $\overline{B}_r $ with $r = M\cdot (|a| + 1)$. Consider the intersection $A \cap \overline{B}_r$, it is a compact set (as it is closed and bounded), therefore by the compactness we can choose a subsequence $\{b_{t_k}\}$ of $\{b_t\}$ which converges to a point $b \in A$. The function $F$ is continuous, therefore $F(b) = \lim_{k \to \infty} F(b_{t_k}) = \lim_{k\to \infty}a_{t_k} = a$, which proves that $a \in F(A)$

Can you explain the without loss of generality part ? Are you using the fact that convergent sequence is bounded ?

I edited, now I use $|a| + 1$ instead of $2\cdot |a|$. Yesyes, I use the fact you mentioned, the exact constant doesn't play a big role here

Nice proof +1..In the last line may be you meant to write  a subsequence $F( b_{t_k} )$ .

Thanks! Yes, I meant this. Actually I am going to a subsequence several times in the proof, I hoped it is clear that rather going to a subsequence we can assume that we chose it initially like that. I'd have to use either triple indices at the end or three different letters, neither contributes to the clarity
